# Filtering multiple time series values in R

Tags: r, filter, time-series, tidyverse

I have a problem with a time series which I don´t know to solve.

I have a tibble with 4 different variables. In my real dataset there are over 10.000 Documents.

```
document   date             author            label
1          2018-04-05       Mr.X                    1
2          2018-02-05       Mr.Y                    0
3          2018-04-17       Mr.Z                    1
```

So now my problem is that in the first step I want to count my articles which are occur in a specific month and a specific year for every month in my time series.I know that I can filter for a specific month in a year like this:

```
tibble%>%
filter(date > "2018-02-01" && date < "2018-02-28")
```

Result out of this would be a tibble with 1 Observation, but my problem is that I have 360 different time periods in my data. Can I write a function for this to solve this problem or do I need to make 360 own calculations?

The best solution for me would be a table with 360 different columns where in every column the amount of articles which are counted in this month are represented. Is this possible?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Sorry I need every item as a seperate list as best with the integer how much documents are counted in the specific month.

Comment: Can you please include desired outcome in respect of sample data given?  I am unable to understand

Comment: Though I have given a solution to split it for different time periods.  Doesn't it is as per your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each result into a separate list, you can do something like this

```r
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_split(substr(date, 1, 7), .keep = F)

<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    document: integer
    date    : date
    author  : character
    label   : integer
  >
>[2]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  document date       author label
     <int> <date>     <chr>  <int>
1        2 2018-02-05 Mr.Y       0

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  document date       author label
     <int> <date>     <chr>  <int>
1        1 2018-04-05 Mr.X       1
2        3 2018-04-17 Mr.Z       1
```

you can further use `list2env()` to save each item of this list as a separate item.

Comment: But is this also possible for me if my document column is of the format character and my date column of the format date?

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of rows for each month-year combination, in `tidyverse` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), 
         year_mon = format(date, '%Y-%m')) %>%
  select(year_mon) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year_mon, values_from = year_mon, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#   `2018-04` `2018-02`
#      <int>     <int>
#1         2         1
```

and in base R :

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
table(format(df$date, '%Y-%m'))
```